# monkeyrunner and EndCall

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I'm using MonkeyRunner to play with simulation of user activity.
All fine but I cannot press EndCall.
To make call I use:

```
device.touch(190, 800, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
```

x,y coordinates of CALL button.

But when I trying to hangup I try :

```
device.touch(230, 700, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
```

x,y - accordingly coordinates of End Call button. 
Nothing happen.Trying press:

```
device.press('KEYCODE_ENDCALL', 'DOWN_AND_UP')
```

Same effect. Trying now to send intent but dont know which intent to use to EndCall.
My device running on Android 2.2.1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This works on an emulator with 2.3 and WVGA:

```
#! /usr/bin/env monkeyrunner

from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner

def main():
    print "waiting for connection..."
    device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

    device.touch(140, 760)
    MonkeyRunner.sleep(15)
    print "dialing..."
    device.type('5551234')
    MonkeyRunner.sleep(3)
    device.touch(240, 740)
    MonkeyRunner.sleep(25)
    print "hanging up..."
    device.touch(240, 600)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks but still no luck on real device. Looks like EndCall not controlled under userspace apps. http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/c6e2de4b0cdbecd7/21b7cf4ee06a7005?lnk=raot&fwc=1

Comment: File "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\test.py", line 9, in main
    device.touch(140, 760)
TypeError: touch: The 3rd argument is required

Comment: The 3rd parameter is now type, which is the type of key event to send. The allowed values are DOWN, UP, and DOWN_AND_UP.

Comment: Yes eventually I made it similar with generating previously recorded   events and pushing them back to android, but this cannot be solution as it geometry related and need to be adjusted per every device.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

`device.press('KEYCODE_MENU', 'DOWN_AND_UP')`

instead of

`device.press('KEYCODE_ENDCALL', 'DOWN_AND_UP')`

After that by the help of arrow key u can move up, down, right and left and go to the END CALL Button and click on it using

`device.press('KEYCODE_ENTER', 'DOWN_AND_UP')`.

Comment: I tried that. During call menu button disabled on my Samsung. Same from monkeyrunner API. Nothing popup.