# How to to end an incoming call using monkeyrunner?

Tags: android, testing, monkeyrunner

I have monkeyrunner up and running: I install my .apk using monkeyrunner and have a `device` object ready. In other words

```
device.press('KEYCODE_MENU', 'DOWN_AND_UP')
```

works perfectly.

I use `expect` to telnet to an android emulator of mine and do `gsm call SOME_NUMBER` to simulate and incoming call.

I try to reject this call in the following manner:

```
device.press('KEYCODE_ENDCALL', 'DOWN_AND_UP')
```

But it does nothing... What do i do wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using

```
gsm call SOME_NUMBER
```

to start the call.
you can use either

```
gsm cancel SOME_NUMBER
```

to reject the call or

```
gsm accept SOME_NUMBER
```

to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no reliable way way to end calls using MonkeyRunner. I'm not sure why this is the case.

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690415/monkeyrunner-and-endcall) offers some solutions.

You could also try doing:

```
device.press('KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK', 'DOWN_AND_UP')
```

Using the headset hook keycode has worked for me on some devices but not others.

The most reliable method that I've found for ending calls using MonkeyRunner is to use menu button. This is talked about in the answers to the question that I linked to above.